# How to get updated column names in sql server without using trigger

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called user with columns like FirstName,LastName,Location,City etc What I wanted to do is After a user Updates his information I wanted to track which are the columns that are updated by the user without creating any trigger. For update info I have used the stored procedure.I want to return updated field column name without create trigger.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [UpdateInfo]  
(@FirstName NVARCHAR(20),  
 @LastName NVARCHAR(1000),  
 @Location NVARCHAR(1000),  
 @City NVARCHAR(400)
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [user] WHERE FirstName = @FirstName)  
BEGIN  
UPDATE [user]   
SET FirstName = ISNULL(@FirstName, FirstName),  
  LastName = ISNULL(@LastName, LastName),  
  Location = ISNULL(@Location, Location),  
  City = ISNULL(@City, City)
  WHERE  FirstName = @FirstName  
END  
END
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and help us help you by providing us with sample data.

Comment: 'For this I have used the stored procedure.' - so what's the question?

Comment: What does "I" refer to? And why a stored procedure? Something needs to have the context of what changed. That is available (roughly) in a trigger. It is also known (or knowable) by the process that updates the row. Maybe CDC can be used?